# Store id into variable and use in another controller in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session

i'm creating a web site for users in MVC3 , one scenario is that the user can create projects and add tasks the project

What i need to do is when i create a project and hit save the website displays a page asking the user if he wants to add tasks to that project or not

I need to keep the variable SelectedProjectID , which you need to set ,  both if you create a new project and also if you press the edit link

so from the edit page you can press "Add tasks" and then you go into the tasks page and press the link "use Task " and that inserts values into the many to many table

i need to have the SelectedProjectID  variable with unique values for each user , because the user can only see his projects and so all the users doesn't add tasks to the same project :)

Is it possible to use session variables in this scenario

HttpContext.Current.Session["SelectedProjectID"] = project.Id 
and then retrieve the value where i need to use it

i know i cannot use the variables as static since that keeps the state for the whole app domain 
if i have the variable as public int , then i cannot use it in the other controller because i need to new the controller and than i get the variable as 0

what is the best way to handle this ?

Comment: I will recommend taking a crash course in web development. But the short answer will be Yes you can use session variables to store information. But there are some pitfalls. You will figure out what is best for you after you get yourself familiar with how all this WebApplication stuff work... Good luck